# Changing file permissions given its symbolic link

Tags: permissions, symlink

Specific USB Hardware is listed here:

```
ls -l /dev/input/by-id/
```

The symbolic link: /dev/input/by-id/usb-Metrologic_Metrologic_Scanner-event-kbd resolves to:   **/dev/input/eventxx**  where xx is an integer number.  In this example event19:

```
ls -l /dev/input/by-id/usb-Metrologic_Metrologic_Scanner-event-kbd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 23 22:02 /dev/input/by-id/usb-Metrologic_Metrologic_Scanner-event-kbd -> ../event19
```

Is there a command that can act upon the symbolic link that will change permissions of the target file?  i.e.

```
chmod 666 /dev/input/eventXX
```

Looking forward to the clever and elegant examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
chmod 666 /dev/input/by-id/usb-Metrologic_Metrologic_Scanner-event-kbd
```

I hope that's sufficiently elegant!

From the [GNU manual for `chmod`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html#chmod-invocation):

> `chmod` never changes the permissions of symbolic links, since the
>   `chmod` system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a
>   problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.
>   However, for each symbolic link listed on the command line, `chmod`
>   changes the permissions of the pointed-to file.

This might be GNU-specific, but since you're running a Linux distribution you've probably got GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as accepted answer:

```
readlink -f  /dev/input/by-id/usb-Metrologic_Metrologic_Scanner-event-kbd | sudo xargs chmod 666
```

- [readlink resolves symlink to /path/file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017500/how-to-see-full-symlink-path)
- path/file piped into args to be processed by chmod